# Program in C- Override an interrupt

Tags: c, keyboard, operating-system, dos, interrupt-handling

I am trying to write a program in c, the compiler is DOSBOX/TURBOC only.
The goal of the program is very very simple: User inserts an integer number N from the keyboard and after that, the program waits for the user until he presses on `N` keys at the keyboards (any key).

I am using setvect and getvect to replace interrupt 9, but it working only once. I mean that when I insert `N>1`, in runtime the program entered only once to the new ISR (interrupt service routine) and not `N` time as it suppose to do.

Here is the program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<dos.h>

volatile int AnyKey_Flag;

void interrupt (*Int9Save)(void);

void interrupt AnyKey_Handler(void)
{
    AnyKey_Flag++;
    printf("%d",AnyKey_Flag); //that line is just for testing
}

void main()
{
    int N=0;
    Int9Save=getvect(9);  //save the old ISR
    printf("Please insert a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    sleep(1);
    AnyKey_Flag=0;
    setvect(9, AnyKey_Handler); //here I replacing the ISR with  AnyKey_Handler

    while(AnyKey_Flag<2*N); //here the program waits until N presses, push and release are counted, so N is actually 2N

    setvect(9, Int9Save); //restore the old ISR
    printf("\nEND");
    sleep(3);
}
```

By the way, after that the program finish (N=1 only), the compiler doesn't recognize any key...

Any help will be appreciated.

Thx,

Haim

Comment: I solved the problem. I should have put Int9Save() call inside the ISR...

Comment: A better question might be why you think programming MS DOS interrupts is meaningful. Do you plan to release your next hardware-related program to MS DOS only, or what? Otherwise, there is absolutely nothing to be learnt from fooling around with this code. Modern Windows programming doesn't use interrupts directly, but drivers. And modern embedded systems don't work like this at all.